# Error using addInitialFiles Method

Tags: fine-uploader

I am having an issue trying to use the addInitialFiles method listed here:

http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#addInitialFiles

I get a javascript error in my chrome dev console that says:

```
1032:381 Uncaught TypeError: uploader.addInitialFiles is not a function
```

This is the code I use to initialize Fine Uploader, and make the call the **addInitialFiles()**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var uploader = $('#fine-uploader').fineUploaderS3({
        request: {
            endpoint: "myfineuploaderbucket.com.s3.amazonaws.com",
            accessKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        },
        signature: {
            endpoint: "/SignatureHandler",
            version: 4
        },
        validation: {
            allowedExtensions: ["gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "bmp"],
            acceptFiles: "image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png, image/bmp",
            sizeLimit: 5000000,
            itemLimit: 3
        },
        retry: {
            enableAuto: true
        },
        deleteFile: {
            enabled: true,
            endpoint: "/DeleteImage/?id=@Model.Id",
            method: 'POST',
        },
        paste: {
            targetElement: $(document),
            promptForName: true
        },
        uploadSuccess: {
            endpoint: "/UploadSuccessful/?id=@Model.Id"
        },
        iframeSupport: { //This path needs to be a blank HTML page and is used for fine-uploader to support IE9 and older
            localBlankPagePath: "/Blank"
        },
        objectProperties: {
            acl: "public-read",
            key: function (fileId) {
                var re = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;
                fileExt = re.exec($("#fine-uploader").fineUploader("getName", fileId))[0];
                uuid = $("#fine-uploader").fineUploader("getUuid", fileId);
                filename = uuid + fileExt;
                key = "/@ViewBag.Id + "/" + filename;
                return key;
            }
        },
        scaling: {
            hideScaled: true,
            sizes: [
                { name: "small", maxSize: 350 },
                { name: "large", maxSize: 800 },
            ]
        },
        callbacks: {
            onDelete: function (id) {
                if (id == 2) {
                    $("#fine-uploader").fineUploader("deleteFile", 0);
                    $("#fine-uploader").fineUploader("deleteFile", 1);
                }
            },
        },
    });

    uploader.addInitialFiles([
            {
                "name": "a3ef2360-881d-452c-a5f6-a173d5291066.jpg",
                "uuid": "a3ef2360-881d-452c-a5f6-a173d5291066",
                "size": "66000",
                "thumbnailUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/myfineuploaderbucket.com/1032/ecdca7bb-fb02-4072-b526-4e51cedb1f2b.jpg",
                "s3Key": "1032/a3ef2360-881d-452c-a5f6-a173d5291066.jpg",
                "s3Bucket": "myfineuploaderbucket.com"
            }
    ]);
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong?  Is addInitialFiles not a method, but an option that needs to be initialized when creating the Fine Uploader instance?  I have tried adding "addInitialFiles" to the options of the Fine Uploader instance as well, and I do not receive a javascript error, but it does not load the initial file either.

I am using the latest version, 5.7.1.

Comment: There is an issue in your code somewhere, but it is not possible to help if you do not provide _all_ of your code.

Comment: Thanks Ray, I just added the full javascript code used to Initialize Fine Uploader and make the call to addInitialFiles().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like any other jQuery plug-in, the Fine Uploader jQuery wrapper returns a jQuery-wrapped element. This means that you are attempting to call an `addInitialFiles` method on a jQuery object. Of course, this method does not exist. If you really want to continue using the jQuery wrapper, you must change `uploader.addInitialFiles(...)` to `uploader.fineUploaderS3('addInitialFiles', ...)`.

But you should know that [you don't need jQuery](http://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/) for any of this, especially when using Fine Uploader. There is [no benefit to using the jQuery wrapper with Fine Uploader](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1310), and you can fix your code simply by forgoing the wrapper (and saving a few bytes) and changing the first couple lines of your Fine Uploader initialization to:

```
var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
   element: document.querySelector('#fine-uploader'),
   ...
})
```

Now, `uploader.addInitialFiles` works as you would expect.

Comment: just a note for React users, you'd need to use uploader.methods.addInitialFiles

Comment: why would you mention that here, in a question that has nothing at all to do with React?